# Espresso-Web testing not working for release app

Tags: android, automated-tests, ui-automation, android-espresso, uidevice

I am testing an app with UIAutomation tool provided by Android (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/other-components/ui-automator). It is working fine but not for some webviews . Then I started exploring the espresso-web (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/web ) library with the automator library and it is working for webviews in debug app but when I tried this in release app then it is not working and giving error message

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities found ...
```

I tried finding out this error and most of the blogs says to use Activity Scenario OR Activity rule to initialise the app but My app is initialised through `adb shell am start`  and for debug I am not getting this message and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please check two types of generate APK with release and build when build types debug is true then working in testing UI automation

buildTypes{

```
 release{
    debuggable false
 }
 debug
 {
    debuggable true
  
 }
```

}